# installing Django 1.3 to Python 2.5 on Mac OS X

Tags: python, django, macos, operating-system

Using Mac OS X v 10.6.7
Django 1.3
Python 2.5

I am trying to run setup.py and install Django to the /Library/Python/2.5 version of Python. By default it installs in the 2.6 folder. Need to re-direct.

Thanks,
Harry

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you are using the ancient Python 2.5? There are a lot of nice things in 2.6, e.g. `with`.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are trying to change the default install path from system python to a different python version. In that case, have you considered [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv)?

You can install virtualenv by running

```
pip install virtualenv
```

It is much cleaner and much easier to manage as the number of projects and their dependencies grow.

Comment: yes and virtual environment wrapper is nice, I use it on my mac as well. http://jamiecurle.com/posts/installing-pip-virtualenv-and-virtualenvwrapper-on-os-x

Comment: And a better example with virtualenv and mac ports - http://www.insomnihack.com/?p=421

Comment: sudo python setup.py install --home=/Library/Python/2.5
This worked, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Found it:

sudo python setup.py install --home=/Library/Python/2.5

Works for Mac OS X

Courtesy of http://docs.python.org/release/2.2/inst/inst.html